# Effect of Randomly Ordered Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I have been asked why and how entering time series data in a random order (i.e. not consecutively in the order they were observed) can have an effect on the outcome of a test for autocorrelation. Additionally, what the relationship between the estimates of the coefficients of the two data sets (ordered by time and randomly ordered) would be. Would anyone be able to help me with these questions? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  In instances like this, it may be easier to show by plots and example than trying to describe the theory.  I would suggest picking a few data sets (at a minimum one with a definite trend upwards or downwards and one that has variation but is stable over time) and plot the data as sorted, three different randomizations, and compare those plots and auto-correlation plots against a plot and auto-correlation for the original data set.

Comment: Hi @Tavrock, thanks for your reply! Do you think I would be right in interpreting this question as the time variable essentially being randomised?

Comment: That was my interpretation of the question.